# Particles rendered with hair system do not show in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm making a cactus using spines rendered using a particle system. When clicking F12 to render they do not show up at all. What did I do?
[image]

Comment: Because thanks to Displacement the Hairs left inside ... if you disable Displacement they are rendered ... just for some reason your file crash any time I opened it. I had to append all objects into a new file and disable cactus material to stop crashing.

Comment: I recommend geonodes for all of this, now, because particle systems do not respect mesh displacement from the shader tree.